# How to escape '/' in codeigniter, php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey guys. I'm having this silly issue with inserting text with forwardslash into cart in codeigniter. When it's plain string it's fine but when inserting, say, "compact / compact" it's not doing it. My guess is that '/' needs to be somehow escaped. I tried hmtlspecialchars(), htmlentities() and even addslashes() - none of the worked. Does anyone know how to do that in php?

When I'm inserting something to cart, I'm doing it like this:

```
$release_barcode = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $release = $this->Lists_model->get_release_by_barcode($release_barcode);

            foreach($release as $row):
            {
                 $barcode = $row->EAN_UPC;
                 $price = $row->product_price;
                 $currency = $row->product_currency;
                 $artist_name = $row->artist_name;
                 $label_name = $row->label_name;
                 $release_name = $row->title;
                 $cover = $row->cover;
                 $item_name = $artist_name.', '.$release_name.', '.$label_name;

                 $data = array(
                                  'id'      => $barcode,
                                  'qty'     => 1,
                                  'price'   => $price,
                                  'name'    => $artist_name,
                                  'options' => array('pic' => $cover, 'currency' => $currency)
                              );

                 $this->cart->insert($data);


            }
            endforeach;

            $this->display_cart();
```

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong here. Can you give me a hint please?

Comment: `/` is a forward slash, not a backslash. What are you inserting the string into that might make `/` a special character that needs escaping?

Comment: its backslashes that need to be escaped, Can we see what part of your application playing up or a section of the string that is playing up please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$string = str_replace('/', '\/', $string);`

Thats works for some of my CI applications.

Comment: A forward slash shouldn't require escaping.

Comment: I understand that. However, why CI requires this is beyond me. But, for certain applications the above single line helps me with the problem. I'll chase it up on the CI forums I think.

Answer (score 2):

Just battled the same issue and the str_replace method didn't work. I got it to accept the forward slash by adding it to the default product_name_rules parameter.

```
$this->cart->product_name_rules = '\/\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';
```